# Chart.js: How to calculate the labelOffset based on the distance between ticks?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Chart.js v2.7.1 using Chrome.
Link to example is https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opbvQZ

How do I set the labelOffset that depends on the distance between ticks, hence with resizing the labels are no longer in the centre (though fiddle show numeric axis it's important that the fix would also apply to a category type axis)

For context, I am trying to centre the axis labels for both the x and y-axis on a bubble chart that reacts with resizing of the browser window.

Code;

HTML;

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS;

```
var data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: [
                {
                    x: 2.5,
                    y: 2.5,
                    r: 15
                },
                {
                    x: 4.5,
                    y: 4.5,
                    r: 5
                },
                {
                    x: 5.5,
                    y: 1.5,
                    r: 10
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            data: [
                {
                    x: 3.5,
                    y: 2.5,
                    r: 40
                },
                {
                    x: 1.5,
                    y: 2.5,
                    r: 3
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
};


var options = {
  elements: {
    points: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
    }
  },
  scales:{
        xAxes:[{
          ticks: {
            labelOffset: 50,
            stepSize: 1
          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'X Axis',
            fontSize: 16,
            padding: 8
          },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            labelOffset: -50,
            stepSize: 1
          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Y Axis',
            fontSize: 16,
            padding: 8
          },
        }]
      },
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var myBubbleChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'bubble',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was helpfully answered on Github by jcopperfield, here is the solution;

```
// centre x-scale label
var xScale = myBubbleChart.scales['x-axis-0'];
var xLabelOffset = (xScale.getPixelForTick(1) - xScale.getPixelForTick(0)) / 2;
myBubbleChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.minor.labelOffset = xLabelOffset;

// centre y-scale label
var yScale = myBubbleChart.scales['y-axis-0'];
var yLabelOffset = (yScale.getPixelForTick(0) - yScale.getPixelForTick(1)) / 2;
myBubbleChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.minor.labelOffset = yLabelOffset;

// update chart
myBubbleChart.update();
```

Comment: You just need to put that inside an animation.doComplete function so the updates occur after any page resizing.